# add dynamic relative layout below another relative layout which is in xml

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have some relative layouts in my xml file. I want to add relative layout dynamically on click of add button below last relative layout added in my xml. I have searched n find some articles on stack overflow about it but everyone has added the layout below some dynamic view.I want to add dynamic relative layout below my static relative layout.

Code-

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
      //get id of relative layout which is in xml
rlOption4=(RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.rlOption4);
}
if(v.getId()==R.id.imageButtonAdd)
        {
            Log.e("onclick","add");
            // Creating a new RelativeLayout
            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,rlOption4.getId());
            relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
            EditText optNew=new EditText(getActivity());
            optNew.setText("Option 5");
            relativeLayout.addView(optNew);
 }
```

Comment: add your `relativeLayout` to `rlOption4` main layout. `rlOption4 .addView(relativeLayout);`

Answer (score 1):

If you change the line :

```
relativeLayout.addView(optNew);
```

to

```
rlOption4.addView(optNew);
```

then optNew will be appended as a child of rlOption4 in your layout.